# Java How TreeSet actually works

Tags: java, treeset

Can somoene explain how TreeSet works that the following output is get ?
Thank you.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    Set<String> fructe = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList("mere", "pere", "banane", "mere", "kiwi", "ananas", "portocale"));
    System.out.println(fructe);
    }
}

[ananas, banane, kiwi, mere, pere, portocale]
```

Comment: Are you trying to understand the underlying implementation of Java's `TreeSet`, or are you trying to understand why the output is in the order it appears in? A `TreeSet` orders elements by their natural ordering, and in the case of Java Strings, their natural ordering is [lexicographical ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order). Since a `TreeSet` is an ordered set, its String representation is the items of the set in order, without duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple, you can consider a `TreeSet` is a `Set`, in which the elements are **unique**.

For further information, the `TreeSet` class extends `SortedSet`, `Set`, `Collection` and `Iterable` as in the image below.
[image: TreeSet]

As a result, elements in a `TreeSet` is **unique and sorted** based on the implemented sort algorithm. The elements of `TreeSet` **must implement `Comparable`** **and override the `compareTo()` method** in order for Java to know how to compare the elements in case that they are not primitive.

You can find more information [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/treeset-in-java-with-examples/).

Hope this can help you with your problem!

Comment: "The elements of `TreeSet` must implement `Comparable`" is not technically correct. You can have a `TreeSet` of non comparable elements, as long as the `TreeSet` was instanciated using a `Comparator` for those elements.

Comment: @GPI oops, my bad. I almost forgot that. Thank you for reminding me!

Answer (score 1):

The OpenJDK implementation uses a
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree

The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

Answer (score 0):

`TreeSet` of strings simply stores the strings in *Lexicographic Order*. Lexicographical Order is same as the *Dictionary Order*, i.e. the way in which words are ordered in a dictionary. Two strings are lexicographically equal if they are of the same length and contain the same characters in the same positions.

If you want a different result then you can use a custom `Comparator`.